# Freeing linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi I was trying to write a function that takes in the head of a linked list and free all the memory it allocated. Here is the original code I wrote.

```
void clear_nodes(List *h) {
    if (!h->next) {
        free(h);
        ***h = NULL;***
    }
    else {
        clear_nodes(h->next);
        clear_nodes(h);
    }
}
```

However it does not work. So I changed it to

```
void clear_nodes(List *h) {
    if (!h->next) {
        free(h);
    }
    else {
        clear_nodes(h->next);
        ***h->next = NULL;***
        clear_nodes(h);
    }
}
```

and now it worked.
Notice the difference between the two, I just wonder why can't I make the pointer to null directly. Is it because it's a local variable or something? But marking a pointer to null should make the pointer point to some memory address that I can't access right? Why would it matter if I do it locally or globally.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `value` of h was passed, and not the `location`, you are not changing the pointer - you are changing a copy of the pointer.

If you changed your function to

```
void clear_nodes(List **h) {
    if ((*h)->next == NULL) {
        free(*h);
        *h = NULL;
    }
    else {
        clear_nodes(&((*h)->next));
        clear_nodes(h);
    }
}
```

You could change it "locally". I *think* I got that second part right... didn't try to compile / run it. I am positive about the first part though.

Comment: yes, but the value of h is an address, even its copy should point to the same address right? now I changed its copy's address to some address that I can't access, doesn't that also affect the original h?

Comment: Yes but if you change the value of the copy, you don't change the value of the original. If I give you an IOU for $100, and keep a copy of the IOU, I can change my copy to say I owe you $10 but that doesn't make it so.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do this NON-RECURSIVELY

```
void clear_nodes(List **h) {
    List * copy = *h;        

    while( (copy = (*h)->next) != NULL){
        free(*h);
        *h = NULL;
        *h = copy;
    }
}
```

Recursivity is generally slower than looping.  If you can try to design without recursive routines.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to explicitly allocate space for `*copy`? Something like `List *copy; while((copy = (*h)->next) != NULL){` etc. With your proposed `List **copy = h;` my brain hurts trying to keep straight in my head that you don't end up overwriting pointers.

Comment: In all technicality, that first line could be List * copy = *h;  Then all (* copy)'s could be turned into simply "copy".

Comment: Yes - that's what I was saying... it would keep things straight in my head, for sure.

Comment: @Floris - I modified as to our comments :-)  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Now that I can follow your code, I can finally upvote it. Although it doesn't address the OP's original question, the "don't do this recursively" advice is sound, and making a copy of the "next thing" before destroying the current object looks reasonable. Although I suspect that it makes the kernel's job of managing memory blocks harder... If you delete "last in first out" you are less likely to cause fragmentation.